# How to display error on specific template?

Tags: templates, wp-config

I know in wp-config.php editing this line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); - on display error
define('WP_DEBUG', false); - off display error
```

I just want only display error in specific template or page.

Comment: Any specific reason why. Just turn debug on sitewide. Really don't see the logic why you would want to turn it on for one page only. And remember, never enable debug on a production site. If you have to, place your site in maintenance mode and then debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PieterGoosen gave some good advice. Focus on that,

But if you really wan it, then you can set debug ON temporarily on your website this way.
In your `wp-config.php` use this instead.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['debug'] ) && 'debug' == $_GET['debug'] ) {
  define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
}
```

Then access your website homepage/any page and add `?debug=debug` at the end of URL.
For example if you have page `www.example.com/about/` then use this link to enable debug.

```
http://www.example.com/about/?debug=debug
```